# How to customize which items TimePicker shows?

Tags: android

I've been programming in Android just for a week now, so my *philosophy* might be a bit rigged from other IDEs. I am used to Visual C#'s style of dealing with components - just drag it on the screen, then choose possible preferences in its menu. That however doesnt seem to work here.

My problem: I am trying to make a simple countdown clock, with the user choosing the time through the `timePicker`. But for that, I need a different style of it than the default. Rather than choosing the "real" possible time, I would like it to have just minutes and seconds, sorted incrementally, so the user can choose "48 min, 9 sec" and press ok. How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `TimePicker` is meant for picking actual times... not quantities of time. So you can't do so using the `TimePicker` provided in the public SDK. You'll have to make your own custom view instead.

To do this, one thing you might consider trying is making your custom `View` extend `TimePicker`. Perhaps you could then override the appropriate methods to reach the desired behavior. It will require a bit of sifting through the [**source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/TimePicker.java/) on your part, however. I'm not 100% sure if it is possible either, but it seems like it should.

Comment: Well. That's disappointing. I don't want to make another question about this - how do I change it from 12h to 24h format?